# Firebase CLI Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

I have an angulardart project that is being hosted on firebase. 
However I can't even get firebase CLI to work for some reason. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Hammy>firebase --version
C:\Users\Hammy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\configstore\index.js:26
                                ...defaults,
                                ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hammy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\configstore.js:3:21)
```

I've npm uninstalling firebase, firebase-tools and then npm install -g firebase and firebase-tools. However I still get the same error. Everything installs fine without errors

- Firebase-tools 8.1.1
- firebase 7.14.1
- nodejs 8.1.2
- dart 2.0.0

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your Node.js version is an older one that doesn't have support for the spread (`...arg`) operator. If you update to Node v8.6.0 or later, the error should go away.